# In what sense is the differential of a linear map is itself?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given $R^n$ and $R^k$ and $L$ is a linear map from $R^n$ to $R^k$. I was told that the differential of $L$ at $p$, $dL_p:T_pR^n \to T_{L(p)}R^k$ is $L$ itself. Here $dL_p(v)(g) = v(g\circ L)\  \forall v \in T_pR^n$. This is really confusing since $L$ and $dL_p$ does not even have the same source space. In what sense should they be "equal"?

Comment: What is a "linear map" between smooth manifolds? Usually linear maps are defined between linear spaces, where the tangent space at any point can be canonically identified with the space itself. Such maps are automatically differentiable, with the differential coinciding with the map itself.

Comment: Sorry that I have edited the question.

Comment: $\Bbb R^n \simeq T_{p}\Bbb R^n$

Comment: No, $L$ itself has $L$ as a differential. Synthetically, this is the simple remark that at every $x$, $$L(x+h)=L(x)+\color{red}{L(h)}+o(h)$$ when $h\to0$. Of course here, the $o(h)$ term is actually zero hence the identity above indicates that, for every $h$, $\color{red}{L(h)}=dL_x(h)$, qed.

Comment: The source space of dL_x is the tangent space of $R^k$ at $p$ rather than $R^k$ it self.

Comment: I see your point. @Bye_World

Comment: @lisyarus is this related to why the [differential of left multiplication in the general linear group is also left multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425617)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that if $V$ is any finite-dimensional vector space, there is a *canonical* (i.e., basis-independent) isomorphism between each tangent space $T_pV$ and $V$ itself. Using the definition of the tangent space $T_pV$ as the space of derivations of $C^\infty(V)$ at $p$, this isomorphism is given by sending $v\in V$ to the derivation $D_v\colon C^\infty(V)\to \mathbb R$, defined by 
$$
D_v f = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} f(p+tv).
$$

Once you make the identifications $T_p\mathbb R^n\cong \mathbb R^n$ and $T_{L(p)}\mathbb R^k\cong \mathbb R^k$, the equation $DL_p = L$ falls out quickly from the definition of the differential.

Comment: Jack Lee, is this related to why the [differential of left multiplication in the general linear group is also left multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425617)?

Comment: @EkhinTaylorR.Wilson: Yes. Left multiplication by a fixed matrix is the restriction to an open subset (i.e., $GL(n,\mathbb R)$) of a linear map on the vector space of all $n\times n$ real matrices.

Comment: Thanks! You can post your comment as an answer to my question.